# Best way to record screen video in Unity on android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, video-capture

Is there any best way to record screen video in `Unity`? There is an Everyplay plugin/tools, but I found a message on forum that the service will be shutdown in near future [(here)](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=everyplay%20shutdown&oq=everyplay%20shu&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i61j69i57j0.2815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) . So is there some options to record video from the screen(or unity `Camera` on scene) to **android/ios** device? Thanks.

Comment: android studio provide the capture screenshot and video, please check logcat or android monitor.

Answer (score 4):

We've built an open-source GIF-recording project: https://github.com/getsocial-im/getsocial-capture. C# examples are in the readme. It records main camera by default.

You can record in 2 modes:

1. `Continuous` mode - capture X last frames.
2. `Manual` mode - capture frames on your own when needed. For example, record a timelapse of the level.

Here's the recording of a game session from the test app. The recorded GIF preview shows up in the end:

[image: GetSocial GIF Capture library]

If you want to mimic the social community of Everyplay, you can also check out our social layer tools ([Activity Feeds](https://docs.getsocial.im/guides/activity-feed/introduction/)). *Disclaimer: I'm from GetSocial.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however, I have very low gif quality with the tool, did I miss any settings ?

Comment: Hey @Dliix, thanks for reporting that on Github (probably, that was you), we'll look into the issue with red color.

Comment: Hey, yeah it was me, sorry about posting here too, and thank you for accepting the pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the PR and contribution @Dliix!

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look on the FFmpeg Unity Asset? This should work for Android and iOS: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ffmpeg-unity-bind-93622

The Asset also has a lot more functions that you'll maybe need, too :-)

Answer (score 2):

(CURRENTLY ONLY FOR ANDROID, WORKING ON THE IOS)

I created a Unity Asset for screen recording which is free to use and easy to integrate with Unity. I am still working on it and hopefully add more features. This plugin will only work on Android(Lolipop or above) devices. I also posted a video tutorial on how to integrate it on your unity project

ASSET DOWNLOAD LINK: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pIN5q30XOy4RXfUsb3J2rBBF4cqlc-ZR

Tutorial LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3zGzbe9V1o

NOTE: The core plugin was developed by Kim (https://github.com/thanh-nguyen-kim/Unity_Android_Screen_Recorder) which I used to create the .asset file.

Hope it helps.